# Magento 2 Multi-site second site domain not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, multidomain, multisite

I have Magento 2.1.7 with 2 websites.

First site is `www.domain.com`

second site is `second.domain.com`

The scope for users is website so that each website has its own users.
The first website everything works great users can get email recover password etc.

The problem is with my second website that i have in a subdomain. Users don't receive any mail from this. If i try to reset the code from backend i get the message user will receive the mail but no mail is being sent.

Probably i haven't done something in the settings correct but i am new to Magento and don't know what i might have done wrong i search the forums but couldn't find a solution.

Also i don't know if this is related to my mx records

```
domain.com. A   111.111.111.111 
second  A   111.111.111.111 
ftp A   111.111.111.111 
mail    A   111.111.111.111 
pop A   111.111.111.111 
smtp    A   111.111.111.111 
www A   111.111.111.111 
www.second  A   111.111.111.111 
domain.com. NS  ns1.domain.com. 
domain.com. NS  ns2.domain.com. 
domain.com. MX  0 aspmx.l.google.com.   
domain.com. MX  10 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. 
domain.com. MX  10 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. 
domain.com. MX  20 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com. 
domain.com. MX  20 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com. 
domain.com. TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:111.111.111.111 ~all"
```

This is how i set up the index.php for the second domain.

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'second';

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

If anyone has any idea thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the email logs on the server? There might be a sort of blocking on the SMTP server side based on the domain. Does not look like there's a reason in Magento configuration

Comment: Yes i have checked the logs there was nothing blocking on the smtp server side.

Answer (score 0):

@ Yaroslav Rogoza you were right i rechecked my logs and found the problem.

It was an authentication problem with google.

```
F=<XXX@xxx.xxxxx.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xx] X=TLSv1.2:XXXX-XXX-XXXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX:XXX CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data: 550-5.7.1 [xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx::x] Our system has detected that this message does\n550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and\n550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review\n550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError - gsmtp
```

So the easiest solution i just disabled the ipv6 for now and everything worked perfect.